# Cambiar consulta sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rendimiento

Tengo la siguiente consulta para obtener un promedio de unos datos de las 52 semanas del año de la siguiente manera:

```
$dates = array();
$firstDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('first day of January 2016'));
$lastDate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last day of December 2016'));

for($i=strtotime($firstDate); $i<=strtotime($lastDate); $i+=86400 *7){
  array_push($dates, date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week', $i)));
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++){

  $sql = "SELECT pr_products.product,
  CONCAT(YEAR('".$dates[$i]."'),'-',LPAD(WEEK('".$dates[$i]."'),2,'0')) AS Week,
  SUM(IF(sw_sowing.type = 'SW', sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS PlantSowing,
  SUM(IF(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6      WEEKDAY('".$dates[$i]."')),'".$dates[$i]."'), sw_sowing.date)/7) >= pr_products.week_production AND sw_sowing.type = 'SW',sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS              production
FROM (
      SELECT max(sw_sowing.id) AS id
      FROM sw_sowing
      WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
      AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = :id_tenant
      AND sw_sowing.status = 100
      AND sw_sowing.date <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY('".$dates[$i]."')),'".$dates[$i]."')
     GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
     ) AS sw
     INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
     INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product
     INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON sw_sowing.id_variety = pr_varieties.id
     INNER JOIN pr_lands ON pr_lands.id = sw_sowing.id_land
     WHERE pr_varieties.code != 1
     AND sw_sowing.id_product = 1
     AND sw_sowing.status = 100
     GROUP BY pr_products.product
     HAVING plantSowing > 0
     ORDER BY pr_products.product";

}
```

declaro dos variables inicialmente que son `$firstdate` qué es la fecha inicial y `$lastDate` que es el fecha final.

Luego hago un for para recorrer las dos fechas y guardo en un array las fechas de los lunes de cada semana.

Luego recorro ese nuevo array para obtener los datos que necesito semana a semana.

Nota: Dentro de la consulta las variables `$dates[$i]` son las fechas de los lunes de cada semana.

En fin, la consulta funciona perfectamente porque me trae los datos que necesito de las 52 semanas del año. El problema es que se demora un poco.

Ya hice indexación de las tablas en mysql, mejoro un poco pero no lo suficiente, la consulta en realidad no es pesada se demora en promedio 0.60 segundos por ciclo.

Quisiera saber si hay una posibilidad de eliminar el for que estoy haciendo y dentro de la consulta agregar no sé, un `WHERE` que compare las dos fechas y me traiga los datos, o si hay alguna manera de mejorar la consulta.

Comment: Sí debe ser posible eliminar el ciclo. No digo que sea fácil, pero debe ser posible. Si tengo tiempo mas tarde y nadie aún te ha sugerido cómo hacerlo, veré si puedo recomendarte algo al respecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias @sstan, estoy revisando también que puedo hacer, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creacion de Procedure(es el ejemplo de como crear la procedure aun no esta terminada):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `promedio` $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `promedio`(in dateStart timestamp,in dateFinal timestamp,in idTenant int)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE cont int default 0;
    DECLARE dateProcesada timestamp;
    /*primer lunes*/
    SET dateProcesada= DATE_ADD(dateStart, INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(dateStart) DAY);
    /*tendrias que verificar bien el tipo de datos para las columnas de la tabla temporal*/
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE promedio_temp (
      `product` int,
      `Week` varchar(10),
      `PlantSowing` bigint,
      `production` int,
      PRIMARY KEY(product)
      );
     WHILE dateProcesada  < dateFinal DO
    /*misma consulta la idea es crear 
     una tabla temporal para sw_sowing de forma tal q el max se calcule en este punto y devolver los datos en esa temporal*/
    INSERT INTO promedio_temp(`product`,`Week`,`PlantSowing`,`production`)
     SELECT pr_products.product,
    CONCAT(YEAR(dateProcesada),'-',LPAD(WEEK(dateProcesada),2,'0')) AS Week,
    SUM(IF(sw_sowing.type = 'SW', sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS PlantSowing,
    SUM(IF(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-  WEEKDAY(dateProcesada)),dateProcesada), sw_sowing.date)/7) >= pr_products.week_production AND sw_sowing.type = 'SW',sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS   production
    FROM (
      SELECT max(sw_sowing.id) AS id
      FROM sw_sowing
      WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
      AND sw_sowing.id_tenant=idTenant
      AND sw_sowing.status = 100
      AND sw_sowing.date <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(dateProcesada)),dateProcesada)
     GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
      ) AS sw
     INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
     INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product
     INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON sw_sowing.id_variety = pr_varieties.id
     INNER JOIN pr_lands ON pr_lands.id = sw_sowing.id_land
     WHERE pr_varieties.code != 1
     AND sw_sowing.id_product = 1
     AND sw_sowing.status = 100
     GROUP BY pr_products.product
     HAVING plantSowing > 0
     ORDER BY pr_products.product;

     /*sumar 7 dias para obtener proximo lunes*/
     SET dateProcesada= DATE_ADD(dateProcesada, INTERVAL 7 DAY);

    end while;

   SELECT `product`,`Week`,`PlantSowing`,`production` FROM promedio_temp;

    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

para llamarla usa esto:

```
$sql="call promedio('$firstDate',''$lastDate',:id_intent)";
```

Comment: Hola Danilo. Estéticamente, el cambio es bueno, pero dudo que tenga algún efecto en el rendimiento de la consulta.

Comment: para mi puede ser que mejore ya que acotaría los conjuntos que devuelven las tablas al hacer los joins y otra cosa mas que puede mejorar el rendimiento, es que primero realice las comparaciones de los campos que tenga indices, en el where de la subquery.

Comment: Como se tratan de inner joins, los motores de bases de datos típicamente  detectan estas condiciones en las consultas y las reordenan automáticamente como lo hicistes. Por eso, en la práctica, no hay diferencia. Si fueran left joins, sería otra cosa.

Comment: Eso no lo sabia tenia entendido que no era tan automático pero si es así fantástico,muchas gracias por la información y ahora me voy a poner a investigar un poco mas con respecto a este tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, es decir que en conclusión, no puedo elimina el ciclo for, sólo debo mejorar la consulta @DaniloBustos

Comment: Si el for me parece necesario para este caso, si podrías usar una store procedures seria distinto y podríamos intentar alguna otra forma para mejorar la performance, ademas estuve averiguando y encontré una forma que podría mejorar el tiempo de ejecución sin usar la función `max` y cruzar dos veces la tabla `sw_sowing`, pero no he  podido probarla aun (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/7416478), según comentarios mejoraría el tiempo de ejecución pero deberías aplicarlo y probarlo si es así, yo apenas tenga pueda la probare.

Comment: Gracias @DaniloBustos voy a revisar también y aplicar este ejemplo y te cuento

Comment: @DaniloBustos tienes un ejemplo de usar los store procedures?, estoy mirando pero no me funciona!

Comment: ahí tendrías un ejemplo,al crearla no me tiro errores pero no la pude probar por que no tengo las tablas, otra mejora que se puede hacer es el uso de una tabla temporal como te puse en el comentario,una duda es una variable :id_intenant?

Comment: Voy a revisarlo @DaniloBustos gracias!

Comment: si id_tenant es una variable @DaniloBustos

Comment: buenísimo entonces, cuando puedas crearla  y dejarla lista para dar solución al problema avísanos y si los resultados de tiempos de ejecución no son lo suficientemente buenos, podemos usarla como  base.

Comment: Ya pude hacer el procedure, pero tome la consulta completa que tengo y la adapte, se demoro 70 segundos en guardar @DaniloBustos

Comment: le agregarle indices a la temporal? puedes probar ademas separando en otra temporal a  `sw_sowing` como en el comentario que te deje, dentro de unas horas podría probar algo, si existe la posibilidad de que por algún medio como github nos pases el dump de la base de datos para poder probarla mejor, seria excelente.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53272/discussion-between-danilo-bustos-and-fabian-sierra).